# SPring JPA can not parse a native SQL Query with a single quote

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to parse this sql query using spring data jpa to use in my application. It is a postgresql qurey using some of the geospatial functions using postgis. This query is basically trying to find all the records in the table which is in a particular search radius of a given longitude and latitude.

SQL Query:

```sql
    SELECT P.ID, P.PLACENAME, P.CATEGORY, P.SUBCATEGORY, A.GEOLOCATION, A.STREETNAME, 
    A.TOWN, A.STATE, A.COUNTRY, ST_Distance(A.geolocation::geography, 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 4326)::geography, false)/1000.00 AS DISTANCE FROM 
    PLATFORM_VENDOR_COMMON P JOIN ADDRESS A ON P.ADDRESS_ID = A.ADDRESS_ID WHERE 
    ST_DWithin(A.geolocation::geography, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 
    4326)::geography, ?, false) ORDER BY A.geolocation::geography <-> 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 4326)::geography OFFSET ? LIMIT 20
```

I'm trying to execute this query under the JpaRepository Interface using:

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT P.ID, P.PLACENAME, P.CATEGORY, P.SUBCATEGORY, A.GEOLOCATION, 
    A.STREETNAME, A.TOWN, A.STATE, A.COUNTRY, ST_Distance(A.geolocation\\:\\:geography, 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 4326)\\:\\:geography, false)/1000.00 AS DISTANCE 
    FROM PLATFORM_VENDOR_COMMON P JOIN ADDRESS A ON P.ADDRESS_ID = A.ADDRESS_ID WHERE 
    ST_DWithin(A.geolocation\\:\\:geography, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 
    4326)\\:\\:geography, :radius, false) ORDER BY A.geolocation\\:\\:geography <-> 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 4326)\\:\\:geography OFFSET :pageNumber LIMIT 
    20", nativeQuery = true)
    List<FindPvNearbyProjection> findAllNearby(@Param("lon") Double lon, @Param("lat") 
    Double lat,
            @Param("radius") Integer radius, @Param("pageNumber") Integer pageNumber);
```

And expecting the named queries to replace in their corresponsing places but somehow spring jpa is not able to translate this information to a sql statement and giving me this error:

```
[ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry\n  Hint: \"POINT(:l\" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry] [n/a]\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:320)
```

> I think the Single quote (') before the `POINT` statement is the culprit but I'm not sure.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating strings in PostgreSQL is like:

https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-postgresql

Instead of using:

`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)', 4326)`

please try this:

`ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || :lon || ' ' || :lat || ')', 4326)`

Comment: The error I think is not in postgresql the problem is in spring framework but I will surely try your method

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to considering when using native queries as sometimes the smallest things could not work.

1. Make sure to check application properties has the correct dialect chosen so spring knows how to read it.

   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2. Create entities that map directly to the native query. The table name @Table(name = "Location") should match exactly to what's in the query.
3. Make sure all named parameters are in the method and test query in DB editor before pasting in @Query

And lastly separating the query on a new line based on keywords like (JOIN, ORDER BY, ETC) helps to visual pick up issues that might be seen in the native query. Like:

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT P.ID, P.PLACENAME, P.CATEGORY, P.SUBCATEGORY, ETC ..."
        + "JOIN ADDRESS A"
        + "ORDER BY B"
        + "OFFSET 3"
        + "LIMIT 20",
    nativeQuery = true
)
```

Comment: Yes I have done all of that except spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true. My other queries are running fine I have problem running just this query